# How to get value inside the span using XPATH?

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to get value 4,023,484 from this span:

[image]

I tried this line with no luck:

```
//span[contains(text(),'posts')]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one to get required value:

```
//span[contains(.,'posts')]/span
```

or

```
//span[normalize-space(text()[2])='posts']/span
```